# Convert array from one type to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to convert an array of Colliders to an array of GameObjects. This is the only way I know how to do this, but it doesn't feel optimal. Is there a better way to do this?

```
GameObject[] GetOverLap(){
    GameObject[] gameObjects;
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius, layer);
    gameObjects = new GameObject[colliders.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++){
        gameObjects[i] = colliders[i].gameObject;
    }
    return gameObjects;
}
```

Here is the full block of code:

```
protected GameObject[] GetOverLap(GameType gameType){
    GameObject[] gameObjects = null;
    if(gameType == GameType._3D){
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius, layer);
        gameObjects = new GameObject[colliders.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++){
            gameObjects[i] = colliders[i].gameObject;
        }
    }else if(gameType == GameType._2D){
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius, layer);
        gameObjects = new GameObject[colliders.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++){
            gameObjects[i] = colliders[i].gameObject;
        }
    }
    return gameObjects;
}
```

It is repetitive, is there anyway to condense it because the only lines that are different in the if/else is the `OverlapSphere/OverlapCircleAll`.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  You could probably make it smaller with LINQ, but probably you'd make an intermediate `List` along the way, and this is solid if old-school.

Comment: What is better in your world? Faster? Less memory? There are many indicators implying what better means. Of course you may shorten it a bit using `gameObjects = colliders.Select(x => x.gameObject)` but this is only shorter, but not faster or better in any way.

Comment: Are you looking for some type of mapper tool/framework? One option might be provided by http://automapper.org/

Comment: I guess I was hoping for cleaner way, because that block is in an if/else statement, and I basically have to do the same thing twice. So I was looking for a global way of doing it.

Comment: You could always move the `foreach` into another method, and call that method inside each section of your if/else.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.ConvertAll. This one looks clean.

Full documentation available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

In short, i would suggest to use [**automapper**](http://automapper.org/) framework.
Because, basically what you are doing is **mapping one class/object to another** one.

Mapping will remove complexity from main code and it will simplify the syntax. Thus, it will look something similar to:

```
GameObject[] gameObjects = null;
if (gameType == GameType._3D){    
     gameObjects = Mapper.Map<Collider, GameObject>(colliders); }

else if(gameType == GameType._2D) {
    gameObjects = Mapper.Map<Collider2D, GameObject> (colliders); };
```

Basically, you will implement all your mapping logic in a common mapper file.
The  automapper does the property mapping by default when property names and types are same in each object:

```
mapper.CreateMap<Collider, GameObject>();
mapper.CreateMap<Collider2D, GameObject>();
```

If property names or types are **different** then, individual mappings need to be defined. Quick sample would look like the following snippet:

```
mapper.CreateMap<Collider, GameObject>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop1, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ForMember(dest => dest.StateName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StateProvinceName));
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop2, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

**and respectively for Collider2D:**

```
mapper.CreateMap<Collider2D, GameObject>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StaffId))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StaffName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use Linq.

```
using System.Linq;  

...

protected GameObject[] GetOverLap(GameType gameType){
    List<Component> collComponents = new List<Component>();
    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    if (gameType == GameType._3D)
        collComponents = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius, layer).Cast<UnityEngine.Component>().ToList();
    else if (gameType == GameType._2D)
        collComponents = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius, layer).Cast<UnityEngine.Component>().ToList();

    foreach (Component c in collComponents)
        gameObjects.Add (c.gameObject);
    return gameObjects.ToArray();
}
```

I generally prefer using Lists over Arrays for general purposes- I like their methods over those available for Arrays. Regardless, I hope this code helps with your readability.

I hope that helps!

**UPDATE:**
Updated code, thanks to @DRapp 's suggestion.

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  Collider and Collider2D objects are not the same and I think would otherwise fail compliation.  However, they are both of type UnityEngine.Component which does have the gameObject reference that can be extracted.  You could just change by linq's...  .Cast<UnityEngine.Component>.ToList() for a direct conversion into same list type.

Comment: @DRapp Ah you're right. I completely overlooked that. Thanks! Editing my post now.